# Springboot 2.6.6 upgrade vulnerabilities

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrading to Springboot 2.6.6 maven dependency check run failed with several vulnerabilities errors

spring-boot-2.6.6.jar: CVE-2013-4152, CVE-2014-0054, CVE-2013-7315 spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty-2.6.6.jar: CVE-2013-4152

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Where are you getting these vulnerability reports from?

Comment: From OWASP dependency check. By running mvn dependency-check:check returns list of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation about how to read the dependency-check reports](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/thereport.html) it is stated that one need to check whether the identified CPE's are correct (false positives mainly occur  for CPE's).

Furthermore:

> Once a CPE has been identified the associated CVE entries are added to the report.

See ["How does dependency-check work"](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/internals.html) for the above quoted text.

So a false positive CPE can result in a false positive CVE.

The common link between the original CVE-2022-22965 which is fixed by version 2.6.6 and the e.g. old CVE-2013-7315 newly listed when upgraded to version 2.6.6 is found via cpe:/:vmware:spring_framework:2.6.6, see the [search result in the NVD database](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Advanced&results_type=overview&search_type=all&cpe_vendor=cpe%3A%2F%3Avmware&cpe_product=cpe%3A%2F%3Avmware%3Aspring_framework&cpe_version=cpe%3A%2F%3Avmware%3Aspring_framework%3A2.6.6). However the exact reason why this old CVE is listed is not known to me.

Concluding as an answer to your question: yes I experience the same, but most probably the listed CVE's are false positives since there are [no vulnerabilities known for Springboot 2.6.6](https://ossindex.sonatype.org/component/pkg:maven/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot@2.6.6?utm_source=dependency-check&utm_medium=integration&utm_content=6.5.0).